# Why does crypt(3) use DES?

Tags: password, history, cryptography

`man 3 crypt` clearly states that it uses DES. I thought DES was deprecated, but I see no notice that crypt would be deprecated.

**Why does it not use AES instead, and is `crypt(3)` deprecated?**

Is it simply a case of "DES is secure enough for the purpose of this library", and that programs should use other libraries for encryption of important stuff?

Comment: Using AES would not make this algorithm any better (except that it would increase the maximum password length from 8 to 16). Fortunately, this algorithm hasn't been in common use for over a decade, it's only supported for legacy. Scroll down in the man page to see the modern methods (on most systems, based on SHA-256 or SHA-512). See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords for the theory.

Comment: `crypt(3)` *may* use DES for backwards compatibility, but usually does **not**. Please read the "Glibc notes" in Linux's manpage. And it's the same on BSD. The OpenBSD's version of `crypt(3)` doesn't even support anything but blowfish (`$2`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crypt` is easily breakable (it was in fact written by Robert Morris, a famous contributor to the early Unix, as a workbench for codebreaking activities) and should not be used for anything important.

From the `crypt` manpage:

> The DES algorithm itself has a few quirks which make the use of the crypt() interface a very poor choice for anything other than password authentication.  If you are planning on using the crypt() interface for a cryptography project, don't do it: get a good book on encryption and one of the widely available DES libraries.

For any real-world use, there are cryptographically stronger alternatives available, such as `mcrypt` and `ccrypt` (which uses AES).

Comment: How come it is good enough for password authentication?

Comment: I think because of the additional layers of security provided by Linux password authentication mechanism: passwords are MD5-salted, and their encrypted value is visible only to the superuser (in any modern system that uses `/etc/shadow`).

Comment: The historical `crypt` algorithm has long been obsolete. Modern systems use a different algorithm, based on iterated SHA-2.

Comment: @Gilles, on most modern systems, the algorithm being used can be encoded in the salt.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, sure. To expand on my previous comment: the `crypt` function supports both historical and modern algorithms, and system tools use a modern algorithm unless explicitly told otherwise.

Comment: How does this *answer the question?*

Comment: @lindhe "How come it is good enough for password authentication?" It's not. DES is **not** used for pasword encryption on Linux.